# Strange css behaviour with hover over span/link

Tags: html, css

I'm currently facing a problem with some css code.
What I'm trying to achieve is when somebody hovers on the link in `#trigger`, the div `#hidden` to show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #hidden {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        #trigger {
            border: 1px solid white;
            background: red;
        }
        #trigger:hover #hidden {
            display: block !important;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hidden">
    This hidden div.
</div>

<span id="trigger">
    <a href="#">Show</a>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to understand why the hell this code refuses to work. 
I have used similar code on many places and it worked just fine.
What's the problem here?

Comment: Your `#hidden` element isn't contained within `#trigger`.

Comment: CSS can't affect elements that occur prior to themselves in the DOM. If `#hidden` appeared *after* the `#trigger` (and the `:hover` was placed on `#trigger`) then it could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div `hidden` is not in the `trigger` div.

You can let your CSS code work as follows:

```
<span id="trigger">
    <a href="#">Show</a>

    <div id="hidden">
        This hidden div.
    </div>
</span>
```

Btw, take in considuration that the absolute positioning div (`#hidden`) will take the x and y of the upper element with an `poistion: relative` or `absolute` as the start point (0, 0). If there isn't any, then it takes the body's x and y.

Comment: It takes the *viewport's* x and y, which is the container for `html` (in turn, the container for `body`).

Answer (score 1):

Place the `#hidden` element inside the `#trigger` element and your selector will work.

On your selector `#trigger:hover` `#hidden` is trying to find `#hidden`.